# how to echo a hr on each 4

Tags: php, loops

```
  'products' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'pid' => string '3' (length=1)
          'name' => string '#122232' (length=7)
          'information' => string 'DSDSD' (length=5)
          'image_tumb' => string '1tumbc4ad490017dc211002cfef359204ca7e154467_VisualVoicemail_Android_original.jpg' (length=80)
          'tag' => string 'Sepatu' (length=6)
          'price' => string '12000000.00' (length=11)
      1 => 
        array
          'pid' => string '4' (length=1)
          'name' => string 'Jam Bagus' (length=9)
          'information' => string 'DSDSD' (length=5)
          'image_tumb' => string '1tumbc4ad490017dc211002cfef359204ca7e_48447427_diaspora_dandy_logo.jpg' (length=70)
          'tag' => string 'Jam' (length=3)
          'price' => string '12000.00' (length=8)
      2 => 
        array
          'pid' => string '6' (length=1)
          'name' => string '#122232' (length=7)
          'information' => string 'awdwad' (length=6)
          'image_tumb' => string '1tumbc4ad490017dc211002cfef359204ca7e10408_710.jpg' (length=50)
          'tag' => string 'Sepatu' (length=6)
          'price' => string '140000.00' (length=9)
```

unlimited.

how do i display them like

```
name
name
name
name
<hr/>
name
name
name
name
<hr/>
```

or insert a hr after 4 times fetching ( currently useing PDO fecthall and foreach ) ?

```
         // displays name loops like "namenamenamenamenamenametounlimiteddata"
        foreach ($db['products'] as $product) {

            echo "<div id='product'>";
            echo $db[product][name];
            echo "</div>";
        }
```

but still no clue of doing the above. my friends say to use % sign in php? is that the best way ? if it is please give me an example how do it the right way, if there is a better way please describe it.

Thanks for looking in.
Adam Ramadhan

Comment: Just count. and then compare current counter with desired number. It's not that hard. None of special skills needed

Comment: wew, i just thout about that, anyway its each 4. not just a 4. if im getting it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($db['products'] as $product) {
        echo "<div id='product'>";
        echo $db[product][name];
        echo "</div>";
        if ($i % 4 == 0)
              echo "<hr>";
        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($db['products'] as $product) {
        if($i && $i%4 == 0) {
                echo "<hr />";
        }
        // your existing echo here        

        $i ++;
}
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/kmoYI)

Comment: $i && ? whats that for ? if 0 ?

Comment: $i says "if $i is not zero".  The && means "and", so then both tests have to be true. This keep it from printing the HR a the top (line 0).

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is right you need to use the % operator called as modulus operator which gives the reminder after division.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($db['products'] as $product) {
        if($i%4 == 0)
                echo "<hr>";

        echo "<div id='product'>";
        echo $db[product][name];
        echo "</div>";     

        $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ops it's suppose to be 1

```
$a=1;
foreach ($db['products'] as $product) {

            echo "<div id='product'>";
            echo $db[product][name];
            echo "</div>";
if($a%4==0){
echo "<hr/>";
}
$a++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter variable $i and increment it each time and check if

$i%4 == 0

then echo hr

Answer (score 1):

From your example, I think you meant the 5th one.
Try something along the line of:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    if($i && $i%5 == 0) {
        // the fifth
    }
}
```